# AngularJS / Ionic Framework - Why are one of my template values not being replaced?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mobile, ionic-framework

So I've been playing around with Ionic Framework (and Angular, by extension) recently - but I have encountered a hitch.

Essentially, I want to be able to define tabs along the bottom of the application using a model.

Here's what I have so far:

tabs.html

---

```
<div ng-repeat="tab in tabs">
<ion-tab title="{{tab.title}}" icon-off="{{tab.icon}}" icon-on="{{tab.iconon}}" href="{{tab.link}}">
  <ion-nav-view name="{{tab.controller}}"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
</div>
```

controller.js

---

```
$scope.tabs = [
{
    title:'Home',
    icon:'ion-ios7-pulse',
    iconon:'ion-ios7-pulse-strong',
    link:'#/tab/dash',
    controller:'tab-dash'
}
]
```

Everything in the ion-tab element works and replaces fine, however, {{tab.controller}} in the ion-nav-view element does not.

I've tried rearranging the elements to see if it makes a difference to what is replaced, but it does not - no matter the order, the ion-tab attributes are replaced by the templating engine, but the ion-nav-view attributes are not.

It's not just the 'controller' hash either, {{tab.title}} is equally not-replaced when present in the ion-nav-view element - also, {{tab.controller}} works in the ion-tab element.

The main thing I noticed was that when the application was served to a browser, the DOM was different for 'ion-nav-view' to what I observe in the editor - which indicates that it might be doing some behind-the-scenes magic. I considered that maybe this magic is causing Angular tags in the element to not be parsed/detected/overwritten for some reason.

If this is the case, is there a way to force Angular to do its templating before any other JavaScript occurs - and if not, does anybody know what is happening here? I'm kinda stumped.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

Turns out this is by design - according to the Ionic team, having the view model name be dynamic causes issues. I have worked around this by just manually specifying each of the tabs I wanted to use and referring to the appropriate field for each in my model.

Not DRY, not elegant - but functional.